# how to deliberately cause deadlock in test cases to guard concurrent bug steadily?

Tags: c, pthreads, deadlock, database-deadlocks

Imagine I have a complex test case which can cause two threads deadlock occasionally. It's not suiteable, I think, to run in CI for guarding concurrent bugs. I want to write a simple test case to cause that deadlock with very high likelihood according to the threads' stacktraces.

However it's still hard to reproduce the deadlock in my case due to scheduling of threads in OS. How do I make sure the deadlock nearly always happens in my case until the bug has been fixed ?
I don't know if there're some tricks that can implement it such as changing OS parameter, setting up specific points for yielding or sleeping.

Comment: What OS is this for?

Comment: @gregspears linux

Comment: You should identify the nature of the deadlock. Is it waiting for a file, database resources, mutex locks, or something else?

Comment: @SimonGoater Let's just say locks, especially acquire it with different order

Comment: You seem to want to cause a specific deadlock scenario in your existing code to trigger consistently.  There might or might not be a simple solution, but the details of any successful approach are going to depend deeply on your code.  Ordinarily, I would ask for a [mre].  I appreciate that it may not be possible to produce one for a situation such as yours, but that would just mean that SO is not a suitable venue for the question.

Comment: There are only two ways to cause a deadlock:  acquire locks in different orders; or escalate locks, for example escalate a read lock to a write lock.  Since the code you are testing acquires locks in different orders, there is no amount of testing anyone can do that would ever rule out a deadlock happening in the future.  It's hard enough to create tests that replicate all aspects of all production uses exactly, and it's impossible to create tests that mimic yet-to-be developed production uses.

Comment: If you've been tasked with creating test(s) to find all possible deadlock scenarios so they can be fixed in ways that do not include creating a defined lock order **and enforcing it**, your task is doubly hopeless.  In any complex system, it's going to be literally impossible to test for all possible deadlock scenarios - there are just too many timing combinations when many threads are involved. And then it's going to be impossible to reliably fix any scenarios you do discover without fixing the fundamental broken nature of acquiring locks without a specified order.

Comment: Given your "Let's just say locks, especially acquire it with different order" comment, I think you already strongly suspected that, if you didn't know it already.

Comment: @Lewis Chan  -- hi -- As you may know, based on comments from the community I've deleted my answer.    On the off-chance you found any part of it useful, the code is [here](https://godbolt.org/z/fsT9oMrr1).  Cheers...

Comment: @AndrewHenle I know we can't check every possible deadlock. What I means, given the deadlock thread's stacktraces in my program, I can estimate what's going on probably. But I need a case to cover that bug. If the case consistently show the bug and after fixing it, it doesn't occur in dozens of times, then we could say it's fixed for the moment.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I know maybe what I'm asking is a little abstract without code illustration. It indeed depends on my code. I'm hoping for an example to show some special techniques.

Comment: I may use gdb `no-stop` mode to easily reproduce the deadlock during debugging. But I still want the gtest case to consistently reproduce it.